# For symmetric matrix $A$ is $XAX^T$ also symmetric?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Given a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ and an arbitrary matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{k*n}$, is the product $XAX^T$ also symmetric?

I know that $XX^T$ is symmetric and I also know that for every symmetric matrix there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ st. $A=UDU^T$ [(Source)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/W12/NotesMatrices.pdf). I don't think the second fact actually helps, but it makes me think this statement is true.

I also tested with a specific example and the result was symmetric but I'm not sure how to actually prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 2):

Prove that $(BC)^T=C^TB^T$, think about $(B_1B_2\cdots B_n)^T=$? and check your question again.

Comment: Ah so $(XAX^T)^T=XA^TX^T$ and since A is symmetric $A=A^T$ so $XA^TX^T=XAX^T=(XAX^T)^T$. Becomes very simple when you start from the definition of symmetry.